# How to retrieve shopping cart items, implementing LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html, onload

How do I retrieve information stored in a js file? I assume I am labelling my node elements in HTML incorrectly

I'm hoping to gain a better understanding of how to retrieve a function node from `localStorage`

Below are the key factors I am trying to get using getElementById into local storage from post HTML.

This is not everything in my listing.html document, I have excluded everything but what I think are essential elements

```html
<div class="listing">
  <div class="container-form">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
      <img class="img" value(src)="1" id="img" src="images/4.JPG" alt="img1">
    </div>
    <div class="infoBox">
      <h5 post="weight" id="weight" value="7.00">7.00 : Under - 16 oz</h5>
    </div>

    <div class="column-bottom">
      <div class="add-button">
        <div class="add-button" method="post">
          <p><input type="submit" onclick="addListing()" class="btn"></input></p>
          <div class="buy-button">
            <span class="price" post="price" id="price" value="60">$60</span>
            <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="window.location.href='cart.html'" onclick="addListing()"
              ;>BuyMe</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to use the function below to store each element from  the post HTML

```
function addlisting() {
  let listing = ['listings'];
  if (localStorage.getItem('listings')) {
    listing = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('listings'));
    alert("added!");
  }
  listing.push({ 'listingId': listingId + 1, image: '<imageLink>' });
  listingsId = listingsId + 1;
  var listingsName = document.getElementById('name').innerHTML;
  var listingsPrice = document.getElementById('price').getAttribute('data- value');
  var listingsImage = document.getElementById("img").src;
  var listingsWeight = document.getElementById('weight').getAttribute('data- value');
  value = parseFloat(listingsPrice, listingsWeight).toFixed(2);
  localStorage.getItem('name', 'price', 'img', 'weight', JSON.stringify(listingsName, listingPrice, listingsImage, listingsWeight));
}
```

here is the `$(document).ready(function(){`  function I'm hoping to implement into my code, I got this from another Stack Overflow page as it was the most fitting however I am yet to understand each component.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#Btn').load(function () {
    let listings = [];

    if (localStorage.getItem('listings')) {
      listings = JSON.parse(localStorage.setItem('listings'));
    }
    listings.push({ 'listingId': 1, image: '<imageLink>' });
  });
});
```

my question again is how do I then execute this function using `onload` Onto a separate HTML, called cart.html. I did not display my cart.html file because there is nothing pertaining to this question on it.  And furthermore how to go about styling `Onload` events that retrieve information from `localStorage`.

P.S.

There is an alert function within my first .js excerpt `addListing()`, that does not fire when clicked. probably a sign of bad programming. I've just never found a straightforward answer

Comment: I think your question is a little vague, I'm not quite understanding your problem. Any way you can try to clear up your question? execute which function? and what is "a new html"?

Comment: There are a number of things wrong, in the HTML and the JavaScript. In the HTML, the `button` element has `class=".btn"`; class names cannot begin with `.` (well, technically they can, but then you have to escape them every time you use them and it gets all confusing so it's easier to just leave them out of class names). The JavaScript is odd in that there seems to be nothing calling `addlisting()` (which you refer to as `addListing()` in text, but that's different, since JavaScript is case sensitive). The `$(document).ready(function(){` construction is usually called outside of any function.